# How to add google docs forms to facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook, forms, google-docs

I'd like to place my google docs form(for newsletter sign-up) on my facebook page.

using this tutorial I was able to create an app, but no content showed http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/adding-iframe-application-to-facebook-fan-page/

So I wanted to know if there was another way of doing this, or anyway of doing this at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with using the iframe that google docs give you and using the url for the application tab on Facebook. The resulting facebook page is blank.

What I did to resolve this is whip up a simple html file that does the embedding from google and placed it on my (ssl encrypted) server. Then I used the url to that file as the application tab URL in my facebook app. Viola it worked.

Is Facebook not allowing embeds from docs.google.com? There's a simple workaround.

Here's the code from my html file on my server with the formkey mangled to protect privacy.

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/embeddedform?formkey=dGhOU" width="500" height="780" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a php class that i've been using. It provides functionality to capture form elements into a google doc.

That's a possibility but requires a larger learning curve if you're not familiar with PHP:
http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/